# php preg_match not working

Tags: php, preg-match

This is for my registration page. I called the regex code in a variable depending on the characters allowed and not allowed inside the textbox.

```
      $txtlastname = $_POST["txtlastname"];
      $txtfirstname = $_POST["txtfirstname"];
      $txtaddress = $_POST["txtaddress"];
      $txtuser = $_POST["txtuser"];
      $txtpass = md5 ($_POST["txtpass"]);
      $txtcpass = md5 ($_POST["txtcpass"]);
      $txtbday = $_POST["txtbday"];
      $txtemail = $_POST["txtemail"];
      $txtcompany = $_POST["txtcompany"];

      $name = "/^[A-Z][a-zA-Z ]+$/";
      $emailValidation = "/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9]+(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/";
      $number = "/^[0-9]+$/";
```

This is my if statement. My problem is even if I input the right format inside the textbox and click submit. The "not valid" message is still popping.

```
if(!preg_match($name,$txtlastname)){
echo "$txtlastname is not valid";
exit();
}
if(!preg_match($name,$txtfirstname)){
echo "$txtfirstname is not valid";
exit();
}
if(!preg_match($emailValidation,$txtemail)){
echo "This $txtemail is not valid";
exit();
}
```

Comment: What are the contents of $txtlastname and other variables by the time they are getting checked?

Comment: The data will be inserted in the textbox. $txtlastname is the name of my textbox

Comment: @uniqueorn I think he meant you to add the actual text (first name, last name) that you tried out in the the textbox in the question

Comment: Which validation if failing, the names or the e-mail address?

Comment: I tried to input the correct one which is Johnson in the lastname it still showed "not valid" but it didn`t get the value I inserted in the textbox. Also,I tried putting numbers in it like Johnson123. "Johnson123 is not valid" showed. It fetched the data I inserted in the textbox.

Comment: @jeroen All of it, the firstname,lastname, and email.

Comment: I mean $txtlastname is the variable I used. I already edited the code I posted here. @jeroen

Comment: Two things to make sure of:

1. Make sure that the `<form>` has its `method` attribute set to **POST**

2. Make sure that the `<input>`s have their `name` attribute correctly set to their respective names in the PHP code (for example the `name` for `$_POST['txtlastname']` would be **txtlastname**)

Comment: Also, seing the http post request may help. As well as pasting here the maximum possible code. Perhaps some of the variabels are overwritten elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

Try this - you didn't add the `iu` or `i` switch.

```
<?php

 $txtlastname = $_POST["txtlastname"];
      $txtfirstname = $_POST["txtfirstname"];
      $txtaddress = $_POST["txtaddress"];
      $txtuser = $_POST["txtuser"];
      $txtpass = md5 ($_POST["txtpass"]);
      $txtcpass = md5 ($_POST["txtcpass"]);
      $txtbday = $_POST["txtbday"];
      $txtemail = $_POST["txtemail"];
      $txtcompany = $_POST["txtcompany"];

      $name = "/^[A-Z][a-zA-Z ]+$/iu";
      $emailValidation = "/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9]+(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/iu";
      $number = "/^[0-9]+$/iu";


if(!preg_match($name,$txtlastname)){
echo "$txtlastname is not valid";
exit();
}
if(!preg_match($name,$txtfirstname)){
echo "$txtfirstname is not valid";
exit();
}
if(!preg_match($emailValidation,$txtemail)){
echo "This $txtemail is not valid";
exit();
}

?>
```

Comment: `iu` flag for `[0-9]` is a non-sense

Comment: Apparently so, but nothing will happen if it is there.

Comment: So if it does nothing, why are you using it? Moreover `/u` flag is useless in other regex, there're no unicode letters here.